# How to connect snowflake privatelink from on prem server and browser?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have setup the snowflake privatelink and its working well from AWS side.

As per my understanding to make it work from on prem, on prem DNS records creation  needs to be taken into consideration for *.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com and as per the company DNS team this is not possible and it does not work as what is expected in case of AWS route53 private DNS scope.

I could not find any useful docs in the snowflake side or any other public domain about the on premise configuration.

I need to connect to the privatelink url or any  URL from the on prem server and browser which will take me through the VPC endpoints and land me in snowflake private link console. I tried to create Network load balancer mapping towards the Private IP addresses of the snowflake related VPC endpoints , but it does not work , throws me 403 access denied .

Answer (score 1):

`@deb-pal` regarding the point "DNS team told its not a good practice to recreate the the total hosted zone records in their private DNS," your DNS team is correct that this has not been a traditional practice. However, this sort of DNS override to support private communications with SaaS and cloud is a growing practice.

Snowflake's version of this is a little more guarded than some. We do not ask you to host anything in the form `<label>.snowflakecomputing.com`. That would have you potentially overriding records where we are clearly authoritative. Instead we ask you to host things in the form `<label>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com`. Snowflake will never host anything in that form.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 Forbidden error occurs when you try to access the Snowflake privatelink endpoint via the internet. This means that your network isn't set up to route traffic to that endpoint via your AWS VPC. You will need to ensure:

1. You have connectivity between your local machine and the AWS VPC. You should be able to ping an ec2 machine with a private IP address from your machine.
2. The on-premises DNS needs to be set up to point the privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com at the AWS endpoint. If your on-premises DNS directs machines to the public IP address, it won't work (as this will be routed through public internet).

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this issue with lots of Snowflake Customers . Their private link works well from AWS Route 53 side but fails to reach the private link endpoint from on-prem.

It seems your local DNS is not able to reach Route 53 CNAME.
You will have to configure DNS forwarding to make sure it reaches Route 53 hosted zone CNAME.